# How to VBA change cell's value (display text) without changing its formula?

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I've a problem with this VBA macro.

```
Sub demoChangeText()
    Application.Range("B2").Value = "Overidden text"
End Sub
```

My test is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60740207/TestChangeText.xlsm). To run this macro, open it in Excel, press `Ctrl+F8` and choose `demoChangeText`.

As the result, this macro changes the value of cell `B2` (the text displayed to us) but clear its formula. I need to change `B2`'s value BUT also need the formula to be remained.

So my question is **How to change the display text of cell without changing its formula?**

*UPDATE*

I ask this question because I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431677/how-to-vba-sends-a-async-xmlhttp-request)

Comment: Don't think that makes sense. The formula is what defines the display. If you want to change the display, then change the formula. If you change the value to "Overridden Text" you basically change the formula to a trivial one that says "Output this text.."

Comment: @Davuz ChrisNeilsen answer your question perfectly. I also attached the solution file in his answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, as it is a bit hard to tell what your underlying requirement is, but here goes anyway:

Several things affect the *display* of a cell:

1. the entered value, if its a constant
2. the result of a calculation, if its a formula
3. the format of the cell
4. the conditional format(s) of the cell, if any

In the example sheet provided you have a formula of `=ROW()&COLUMN()` which returns a string result of `22`

You can make this *display* something else by applying a cell format,
eg a format of `0;0;0;Ov\e\r\ri\d\d\e\n t\ext` will display *any* string value as `Overridden text`

This can by applied with VBA with

```
Range("B2").NumberFormat = "0;0;0;Ov\e\r\ri\d\d\e\n t\ext\s"
```

or

```
Range("B2").NumberFormat = "0;0;0;""Overridden texts"""
```

Comment: + 1 Nice Explanation :) Yes this is one way to change the display text.

Comment: +1 You can also enclose in quotes rather than escaping the format of each letter. `"0;0;0;""Overridden texts"""`

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen Awesome! This is the test file updated with your answer https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/2012/TestChangeText.xlsm

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you very much! It work for me! A very well tip with VBA & Excel.

Comment: I needed to do the same thing but with an integer. So I did `Range("B2").NumberFormat = 5`