# How to VBA sends an Async XMLHTTP request?

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

To get data from a webservice in Excel, I have created an excel addin provide function to get it; user just need type in cell:
`=sendRequest("http://webservice.com")`

I have 2 excel files to demostrate the `sending request` in two methods: 1.[synchronous](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60740207/TestHttpReqest%20-%20Sync.xlsm) and 2.[asynchronous](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60740207/TestHttpReqest%20-%20ASync.xlsm)

In `sync` method, the function can send request and get data normaly. But, if we **have 100, 200 cells** that call it, it will take Excel a huge amount of time waiting; which also makes Exel to be **not respoding**.

My current solution for this is to use `async` method as [below code](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/)

```
Public Function sendAsyncRequest(URL)
    'other statement

    ' Get some stuff asynchronously.
    xmlHttpRequest.Open "GET", URL, True
    xmlHttpRequest.send
    sendAsyncRequest = xmlHttpRequest.responseText
End Function
```

But the cell's value is alway is zero 0 instead of repsone text.

I must use my handler class to bind it with `OnReadyStateChange` of `xmlHttpRequest object` to set response text into cell. But then, it also clears the cells' formulas.

So my question is **How to change the display text of cell without changing its formula?**

I also welcome another solution to send request and get return value under `async` method.

Comment: My answer has a critical downside and absolutely should NOT be the accepted one. Please uncheck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the downside of the solution stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434587/248616), the proper way to get the async return value for the function is to 1) **cache** your `request's url => returned value` to a collection/dictionary, and then 2) **refresh** your formula

Answer (score 1):

This is my [solution file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/2012/TestHttpReqest%20-%20ASync.xlsm) for your question; indeed it is updated from your [async test file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/60740207/TestHttpReqest%20-%20ASync.xlsm).

Based on [this discusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430370/248616), you can `change the display text of cell without changing its formula` by using Range(yourCellAddress).NumberFormat = "0;0;0;""Value to display"""

So to your question, the solution is

1. In your `sendAsyncRequest` function replace the return line as

   `sendAsyncRequest = "anything other than numbers"`
2. In your `ReadyStateChangeHandler` sub, replace

   `Application.Range(cellAddress).Value = XMLHttpReq.responseText 'return responseText to cell`

by

```
cellDisplayText = XMLHttpReq.responseText
Range(cellAddress).NumberFormat = "0;0;0;""" & cellDisplayText & """"
```

Comment: I also refactor the solution for a better code here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/2012/TestHttpReqest%20-%20ASync%20-%20NN.xlsm

Comment: One downside of this solution is that the value we see as the `displayed text` is NOT actually the cell value; the cell value is  "anything other than numbers". So if the cell A1 's `displayed value` is 122 and we use it in a formula of cell A2, say `=A1+1`, then the value is NOT 123 but results as error (due to adding string to a number)