# EXCEL VBA, PARSING & REQUEST UPDATEDATA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, parsing

I have a some question. I want to parsing XML realtime data some website.

I'm using below Function.

```
Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String

Dim HTML As String
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .Send
    GetHTML = .ResponseText
End With

End Function
```

But, It doesn't respond recent(=renewed data) data.
Just, first request data are holding.

How Could I get recent data from website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to VBA sends an Async XMLHTTP request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431677/how-to-vba-sends-an-async-xmlhttp-request)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HOW TO VBA SENDS AN ASYNCH XMLHTTP REQUEST?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11431677/4088852)

Comment: How are you calling this function?