# How do I change the text of a cell without changing the formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. This question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429493/how-to-vba-change-cells-value-display-text-without-changing-its-formula) but the answer seems way too hackish. Is there a better way to change the value of a cell without changing the underlying formula in it? I've tried target.text="changed" but that gives me an error of "Object Required"

The reason I ask is that in a UDF you can change the display of the cell but the formula remains there. How can I do this outside of a UDF?

EDIT:

In the example below, myudf and my_udf appear to do the same thing and everyone is telling me to just do NumberFormat. The problem is that Numberformat will change the cell permanently. If you entered "=my_udf()" in A2 then just go back and type some random text there. Unless you go back and manually re-format the cell (or enter in an excel built-in function), it will display "ThisThatThere".

Module1

```
Function myudf()
    myudf = "ThisThatThere"
End Function

Function my_udf()
    my_udf = "Temporary"
End Function
```

ThisWorkBook:

```
Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal target As Range)
    If target.HasFormula Then
        If LCase(target.Formula) Like "=my_udf(*" Then
            target.NumberFormat = "0;0;0;""ThisThatThere"""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if you just mean the number format then right click on the cell > format > number format. A format mask can be entered here that affects how the value of the cell is displayed. E.g. `# "magic hats"` would display whatever number the cell has as a value followed by "magic hats". If this is not what you meant then consider rewording your question - it is not that easy to follow what you actually are looking for!

Comment: Type in "=sum(1,2)" and the cell will display "3". The formula will still exist in that cell. The UDF thus changes the cell's display value while keeping the function without the hack you suggest.

Comment: I'm not clear on this question. `SUM` isn't a UDF, so not sure of your point with that. I wouldn't really call custom formats a hack. Also, "display" could mean a couple of things. Actual examples would probably get you a better answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "hack". The number format functionality I suggested is standard Excel behaviour which is to display the result of a cell, either a constant or the result of evaluating a formula. Also, I am afraid I don't understand your comment. The result of `=sum(1,2)` is 3, so that is why (by default) the cell will display 3. Apologies if you do, but are you familiar with how spreadsheet programs work and what a "formula" in Excel is? You mention you know how to do this with a UDF. I am 99% certain the UDF could only be changing the number format.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey: Please see my edit. "I am 99% certain the UDF could only be changing the number format"...If that was the case then the formatting of myudf would stick like it does in my_udf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy if the formula returns a **number value** rather than a **text value** .Place a formula in a cell, select it and run:

```
Sub ChangeText()
    Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    mesage = DQ & "override" & DQ
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = mesage & ";" & mesage & ";" & mesage & ";"
End Sub
```

By itself, a **UDF** , like a non-VBA worksheet formula, can only return a value to a cell.................the best the value can do it to affect conditional formatting.

Comment: But then the format sticks if you then go back and enter text in the cell.

Comment: **NO!!**...........If you place a UDF or a regular formula in the cell  that **returns a numerical value**, the macro-supplied text will be visible..............if you later manually enter text in the same cell, **your* manual text will be visible!

Comment: I never said the UDF would necessarily be numerical

Comment: You are correct!............If you have a non-numerical **UDF** , please ignore my post.